# The radio buttons and checkbox do not show the alert message after clicking, Can you look if I made a mistake?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
<title> Functions </title>
<script>
```

This function serves the purpose of display 2 or 3 pollutant ppm levels with in a single alert message (pop-up on the html page)

```js
function pollutant_level_multiple()
{
if(!document.getElementById("co").checked && 
document.getElementById("no2").checked && 
document.getElementById("voc").checked == true)
{alert("CO=394 ppm");
}
else if(document.getElementById("co").checked && 
!document.getElementById("no2").checked && 
document.getElementById("voc").checked == true)
{alert("CO=394 ppm");
}
else if(document.getElementById("co").checked && 
document.getElementById("no2").checked && 
!document.getElementById("voc").checked == true)
{alert("CO=394 ppm");
}
else if(document.getElementById("co").checked && 
document.getElementById("no2").checked && 
document.getElementById("voc").checked == true)
{alert("CO=394 ppm");
}
}
```

This function display only one pollutant ppm level at once.

```html
function pollutant_level_individual()
{
if(document.getElementById("co").checked == true)
{alert("CO=394 ppm");
}
else if(document.getElementById("no2").checked == true)
{alert("CO=394 ppm");
}
else if(document.getElementById("voc").checked == true)
{alert("CO=394 ppm");
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>

Which of the following pollutant level would you like to know?
<ol>
```

I used radio button to give the user freedom to view the pollutant levels individually or multiple at once. 'onclick' is the one which executes the appropriate function in the `<script>` tag.

```html
Would you like to view ppm levels individually or multiple values at once? 
&nbsp Individually: <input id = "radio1" type = "radio" name = "indimul" 
onclick="pollutant_level_individual();"/> &nbsp Multiple at once: <input id 
= "radio2" type = "radio" name = "indimul" 
onclick="pollutant_level_multiple();" /> 
<li> Carbon-monoxide: <input id = "co" type = "checkbox" name = "CO 
indicator" onclick = "pollutant_level_multiple();"/>  </li>
<li> Nitrogen-dioxide: <input id = "no2" type = "checkbox" name = "NO2 
indicator" onclick="pollutant_level_multiple();"/> </li>
<li> Volatile Organic Compounds: <input id = "voc" type = "checkbox" name = 
"VOC indicator" onclick="pollutant_level_multiple();"/> </li>
</ol>

</form>

</html>
```

Comment: Seems like it's working as long as you make a checkbox selection before clicking a radio button.  Also (FYI), an `ol` may only have `li` elements as direct children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your question actually, there are multiple areas that the above code needs to be improved.

1. If condition- Use of else if in multiple cases should have been different
2. Individual/Multiple is the direction of the code, the driving function is missing I added

please find the working snippet below and let me know if further help is needed.

```js
        var ClickFun;

       function setTheAlertFlow(flow){
          if(flow=="mutliple"){
            ClickFun=pollutant_level_multiple;
          }else{
              ClickFun =pollutant_level_individual;
          };
          ClickFun();
       }
        function pollutant_level_multiple() {
            var ppmLevels = '';

            if(document.getElementById("co").checked ){
                ppmLevels += "CO=394 ppm" + " "
            };

            if(document.getElementById("no2").checked ){
                ppmLevels += "NO2=394 ppm" + " "
            }

            if(document.getElementById("voc").checked ){
                ppmLevels += "VOC=394 ppm"
            }
             

             if(ppmLevels){
                alert(ppmLevels)
             }else{
                 alert("PPM No PPM checkboxes selected")
             }
            
                
                
        }
        function pollutant_level_individual() {
            if (document.getElementById("co").checked == true) {
                alert("CO=394 ppm");
            }
             if (document.getElementById("no2").checked == true) {
                alert("NO=394 ppm");
            }
             if (document.getElementById("voc").checked == true) {
                alert("VOC=394 ppm");
            }
        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
    <title> Functions </title>
    <script>

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>

        Which of the following pollutant level would you like to know?
        <ol>
            Would you like to view ppm levels individually or multiple values at once? &nbsp Individually:
            <input id="radio1"radioG type="radio" name="indimul" value="individual" onclick="setTheAlertFlow(this.value);" /> &nbsp Multiple at once:
            <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="indimul" value="mutliple" onclick="setTheAlertFlow(this.value);" />
            <li> Carbon-monoxide:
                <input id="co" type="checkbox" name="CO indicator" onclick="ClickFun();" /> </li>
            <li> Nitrogen-dioxide:
                <input id="no2" type="checkbox" name="NO2 indicator" onclick="ClickFun();" /> </li>
            <li> Volatile Organic Compounds:
                <input id="voc" type="checkbox" name="VOC indicator" onclick="ClickFun();" /> </li>
        </ol>

    </form>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear from your question, but I think you are looking for something like this:

```js
var polutantsPPM = { CO: 394, NO2: 224, VOC: 122 };

function getReportString(polutantId, polutantsPPM){ return polutantId + " = " +  polutantsPPM[polutantId] + "ppm"; }

function pollutant_level_individual() {
    if(document.getElementById("co").checked) { alert(getReportString("CO", polutantsPPM)); }
    if(document.getElementById("no2").checked) { alert(getReportString("NO2", polutantsPPM)); }
    if(document.getElementById("voc").checked) { alert(getReportString("VOC", polutantsPPM)); }
}

function pollutant_level_multiple() {
    var msg = [];
    if(document.getElementById("co").checked) { msg.push(getReportString("CO", polutantsPPM)); }
    if(document.getElementById("no2").checked) { msg.push(getReportString("NO2", polutantsPPM)); }
    if(document.getElementById("voc").checked) { msg.push(getReportString("VOC", polutantsPPM)); }
    alert(msg.join("\n"));
}
```

```html
<p>
    Which of the following pollutant level would you like to know?
</p>

<ol>
    <li>Carbon-monoxide: <input id="co" type="checkbox" name="CO indicator"/></li>
    <li>Nitrogen-dioxide: <input id="no2" type="checkbox" name="NO2 indicator"/></li>
    <li>Volatile Organic Compounds: <input id="voc" type="checkbox" name="VOC indicator"/></li>
</ol>

<p>
    Would you like to view ppm levels individually or multiple values at once? &nbsp;
    Individually: <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="indimul" onclick="pollutant_level_individual();"/> &nbsp;
    Multiple at once: <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="indimul" onclick="pollutant_level_multiple();" />
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the radio buttons and checkboxes in your code aren't syncing. I think I was not that clear with my problem statement.